# ESD array power and protect from same source

Tags: usb, zener, esd

I am working on incorporating ESD protection for flash circuitry on ESP32 custom PCB board, and after initial research, ordered an ESD Array (CM1293A-04SO) from digikey with [datasheet here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CM1293A-04SO-D.PDF)

Attached in the circuit diagram below, showing

- USB Rx, Tx, and Pin 0 connecting to 3 channels of the array, and
- Handmarked "Flash_3.3V" netlabel connecting to Channel 3,4 via Blue Line and connecting to IC Power Source at pin 5 via Red Line.

My questions is regarding the power line (2 options drawn in red and blue), and I am wondering if the array can simulataneously power and protect the incoming power from USB line.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I got this idea from another protection array RClamp7522T with [datasheet link here.](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/2R000000HTqQ/iEJdTMWfTgfi7KiSi1OQ6ZvqU_A4rcQHQVQUbS4fs.w) with similar electrical circuit ( but higher pricing, with lower capacitance, higher protection range for ESD, a shared zener diode, and no power source), where it shows on page 7, that IC can protect power circuit as well. Please see screenshot

[image: for page 5 here.]

Comment: I came across the post mentioned below where someone said ESD pulse can be handled by the bypass capacitors which I have in place. I guess, I need to build the circuit and test it out myself.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/401699/esd-diode-selection-based-on-vcc-of-the-ic?rq=1

Comment: Yes, either will protect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I learned and answered my original Questions after some R&D :

ESD protection is different for

- Digital I/O Lines
- Power Lines

Digital IO Lines :

- as they are usually one way Industry preference if for high preference for unidirectional TVS
- Additionally CMOS inputs are VERY sensitive to negative spikes, and unidirectional TVS have IV characteristic curves where cutoff/forward bias for negative spike is MUCH less than Positive spike
- Power Dissipation Requirement is low, order of milliWatts

Power Lines :

- Require Large Power Dissipiation (watts)
- Industry practise is to use bidirectional TVS's

The above IC being used and tested, and even thoough working, WILL not provide rectification for power, as it is rated ONLY for ~250milliWatts.

Going to replace :-

1. Digitial IO Protection with : Applied-Power-AU3321D5_C393856 @ LCSC $0.03
2. Power Line Protection with : MMBZ5V6ALT1 @ Digikey (0.10), and LCSC @ $0.03 with 40Watts sinking capability.